# Difference in restart and restart_policy in docker_compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file for some services, among them an airflow-webserver. I realized that I can both add `restart` and `deploy-restart_policy` to the compose file. I tried searching for a difference between the two, but could only find posts discussing the individual settings (like `on-failure` or `always`).

- What is the difference of setting the configuration?
- Which should I use?
- Is it a versioning issue, e.g. `restart` is from older versions and `deploy-restart_policy` is the newer one?

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  airflow-webserver:
    container_name: airflow_container
    image: puckel/docker-airflow
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - dataworld
    volumes:
      - ./airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./airflow/logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `restart` and `deploy.restart_policy` options configure the same thing but depend on the way you run your containers:

- `restart` is used by **Docker Compose**
- `deploy.restart_policy` is used by **Docker Swarm**

The `deploy` option is used for **Docker Swarm** only and is ignored by **Docker Compose**.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy) on `deploy.restart_policy`:

> Configures if and how to restart containers when they exit. Replaces `restart`.

And [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart) about `restart`:

> The `restart` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode.